# How to solve grpc Deadline Exceeded error？

Tags: python, go, protocol-buffers, rpc, grpc

I have grpc server which write by go and a python client, sometimes, the errors occurred as below:

```
eggs/grpcio-1.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/grpc/_channel.py\", line 432, in _end_unary_response_blocking\n    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)\nInternalServerError: Deadline Exceeded\n"}
```

[grpc Deadlines concept](http://www.grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#deadlines)：

> gRPC allows clients to specify a deadline value when calling a remote
>   method. This specifies how long the client wants to wait for a
>   response from the server before the RPC finishes with the error
>   DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. On the server side, the server can query the
>   deadline to see if a particular method has timed out, or how much time
>   is left to complete the method.
>
> How the deadline is specified varies from language to language - for
>   example, a deadline value is always required in Python, and not all
>   languages have a default deadline.

is there way to solve this error?

Comment: Did you write both client and server? How looks the code? How does the server handle timeouts? How does the the client handle timeouts?

Comment: When you ask "is there a way to solve this error?", you haven't yet made the case that the error needs solution. gRPC is telling you that the RPC did not complete during the time that you allowed for it to complete - okay, well, what do you want your code to do next? Retry it? Try a different RPC? Report an error to your code's user?

Separately, it is no longer the case that a deadline is always required for Python; I'll work on getting that documentation updated.

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle thanks for your reminder, I think I should describe this case in detail. I want to know why the RPC cannot complete with the deadline, is the size of message stream is too big or network issue? Can I change the deadline value? I did't find any document to explain it.

Comment: When invoking an RPC with gRPC Python, not passing a timeout value means "no timeout" or "infinite timeout". What causes RPC timeouts is... just about anything you can imagine would, but generally some problem on the client interfering with the RPC being processed within the allotted time, some problem on the server interfering with the RPC being processed within the allotted time, or some problem on the network getting bytes exchanged between the two.  Are you in control of your server? Are you observing that your server completes the RPC in time?

Comment: [Separately, here's that documentation correction](https://github.com/grpc/grpc.github.io/pull/482).

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle It is great!! Thanks for your help, I take control of my server, I found the timeout is 10 seconds, most RPC can be processed within hundred milliseconds, only just a few RPC doesn't completed in time, but i didn't find the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment above, deadlines can be just about anything between the client and server, including the network and implementation of the server. As you are talking over a network, deadlines should be expected occasionally, for example during package losses. In general, there are a couple of options on what you can do here:

- Optimize the server implementation to handle your requests faster.
- In case the client sets a short deadline, increase this.
- Handle the deadline errors gracefully by:

  - Retrying. Just make sure to use an exponential back-off, so you don't make the problem worse in case of a server overload situation.
  - Report an error up-streams.
  - Sometimes it may also be possible to fall back to not use that grpc call and degrade the experience.

Answer (score 0):

**Ref- [Spring Boot + gRPC Deadline Example](https://www.javainuse.com/boot3/grpc7)**
According to the gRPC documentation the gRPC client has no default timeout. So the gRPC client will keep on waiting indefinitely.
So if you are getting a deadline exceeded exception it means that at the client end a timeout has already been configured using gRPC deadline.
 So if you do not want to get this exception there are 2 solutions -

1. Improve the gRPC server performance so that the gRPC client gets the
   response before the timeout configured using gRPC deadline.
2. Increase the gRPC client timeout configured using gRPC deadline. So the
   gRPC client will wait for more time to get the response from the server.