# BigtableToAvro consistently hangs: ping error Deadline exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using provided BigtableToAvro template to do BT backups. It starts, well, but then consistently hangs on what looks to be shuffling.

Full stacktrace from error is in details, main error looks like following: (I was unable to post with proper formatting,no matter how I tried, see full stacktrace list below)

Job eventually succeeds, but half of the time spent idling with 2-3 workers remaining, up from max of 40 at the peak time. Job always take slightly more than 1h to complete, which point to some built in 60 minutes timeout somewhere.

My job parameters doesn't specify number of shards and from what I can tell template doesn't make use of GroupByKey, I am not sure why it is shuffling :-/

I tried to run template with shuffle service, but it looks like it is not possible to enable it for templates.

Screenshots from the Dataflow console and CPU usage on one of remaining workers

- [Dataflow console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYusK.png)
- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdvbU.png)
- [full error gist](https://gist.github.com/redbaron/769484a1aa6ea407a8483281bccf592e)

**I did follow** link from the error, but found nothing applicable from my case: there is no load on nodes, possibly no shuffle happening and only 2-3 worker VMs stay up until timeout expires.

Comment: found [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973191/how-to-solve-grpc-deadline-exceeded-error) which they mentioned that a possibility could be the timeout on either the server, the client or the netwrok it self.